# Training material for sound effects editing / foley

Tags: training, practice, foley, editing

Does anybody know of free training material for sound effects and foley? What I'm thinking of is a movie clip in a proper format for editing, with a separate music track and vocal track provided as audio files. Preferably something very varied with different types of sounds and such.

I've tried redoing sequences from movies by muting and using the released soundtrack to fill in the music, but I really miss having the voices to work with too.

Suggestions for movie scenes with little or no dialogue that would be suitable for the purpose are appreciated too.

Answer (score 2):

The first movie that came to my mind is "Le Dernier Combat" directed by Luc Besson. It's a "mute" film, there are only like 2 words or something like that throughout the entire film. It's really good and there are many scenes that fit your description http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0085426/ . You could also look out for short films or short animated films (like Pixar short films) that normally they don´t have many dialogues (here's an example, I did a Sound Design re-make for "Lifted" a Pixar short film http://youtu.be/thPuWNGx214 ) or you could just re-make any scene of your favorite movies, even if they have Dialogue, and practice ADR also!